# Storing array of floats in Postgres on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

How would I go about doing this? Is it advisable?

I have a table called "Item" with columns "name" and "price".

Price changes all the time and I want to store all the changes so I can graph them.

I was thinking "price" should be an array? Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a separate table to track the price history. Something simple like this:

```
create_table :item_prices do |t|
    t.integer :item_id, :null => false
    t.decimal :price,   :null => false, :precision => 7, :scale => 2
    t.timestamps
end
```

Note that the `price` is a `decimal`, not a `float`. Never ever use floating point for money.

Then in `Item`, something like this:

```
class Item
    has_many :item_prices
    before_save :update_price_history, :if => :price_changed?
private
    def update_price_history
        self.item_prices.create!(:price => self.price)
    end
end
```

A nice advantage of this is that you track when the price changed as well as the price itself, that might make your graph look a bit more sensible.

Comment: great answer. I was thinking about a separate table after I wrote this question. It would enable me to track some other things as well if I needed to in the future.